# Lose of decimal point when editing GridNumericColumn in syncfusion datagrid

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

When I am editing a Syncfusion GridNumericColumn cell (which has a value inside it) and I delete the two numbers after the decimal point, the decimal disappears and has to be manually retyped...

Is there a way to make the decimal point stay visible unless I press backspace one more time?

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

In GridNumericColumn, we have loaded the SfNumericTextBox for editing. And we cannot able to hold the NumberDecimalSeparator when we delete the decimal value in SfNumericTextBox. If we delete the decimal value, the NumberDecimalSeparator will be removed this is the behavior of the SfNumericTextBox.

Regards,
Sivaraman S

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. Are there any workarounds?